# Convergence in probability and boundness in probability with respect to sample mean and sample variance

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, convergence, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

This is a question about the convergence in probability and boundness in probability.

Suppose $X_i \overset{\textrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} (\mu, \sigma^2 )$ for $i=1,2, \cdots, n$.

Denote $\overline{X}$ and $\hat{{\sigma^{2}}}$ as the sample mean and the sample variance respectively.

Then prove the following holds for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\frac{x-\overline{X}}{\hat{\sigma^2}}-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} = O_p (n^{-1/2}) $$

Central limit theorem, Strong law of large numbers, Slutsky’s theorem are available.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your own attempt?

Comment: @Zhanxiong In fact, I have no idea how to control with the sample variance since it is in the demoninator. It is hard to apply central limit theorem with the sample variance since the 4-th moment might not exist.